# find the volume of a container based on percipitation and daily usage

Tags: algorithm, math

ive been trying to solve this question but i dont know how to mathematically approach this.

we have an array including daily captured percipitation. we have another array of same length that has the daily water usage.
the question is how big the container must be inorder to save water through the dry days which percipitation is 0.

i tried to solve this by finding a contigous subarray with the smallest sum, but to no avail.

Comment: If this is a math algorithm question, it's better suited for the math stack exchange. If this is a programming question, you should specify the programming language and share the code you've attempted to solve the program so far. That should include some sample data.

Comment: its a math and programming question.
example: 
`Percipitation = [ 10, 6, 2.9, 1.1, 5, 0]`
`Usage = [ 6 , 4, 7, 3 ,0 ,4]`
in this case the container should be minimum 10 m³ big to have water for every day. 
the overflow is not a problem

Comment: Ali, one way to start approaching a solution is to first imagine you have an infinite container. You will get through all the days and find that the minimum amount of stored water is greater than zero, and then you can reduce the size of the container, or it's zero, and even with an infinite container you don't have enough water. If the minimum is greater than zero, try setting a large, finite value. How does that change the minimum? Reduce it again, what happens? As you work through those results, try to imagine how you could adjust the size to be just enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container must be sized that it can buffer between the minimum and the maximum storage evaluated by a simulated season:

```
double[] percipitation;
double[] waterUsage;
…
double volume = 0;  //  assuming empty Container at beginning
double maxVolume = 0;
double minVolume = double.MaxValue;

for (int i = 0; i < percipitation.Length; i++)
{
    double surplus = percipitation[i] – waterUsage[i];

    if (surplus > 0)
    {
        //  store unused water assuming unlimited capacity
        volume += surplus;
    }
    else
    {
        //  consume stored water (surplus is <= 0)
        //  simulated volume might become negative!
        volume += surplus;
    }

    //  register limits reached so far
    maxVolume = Math.Max(maxVolume, volume);
    minVolume = Math.Min(minVolume, volume);
}
```

Container must be sized to `(maxVolume – minVolume)` plus safety margin. The necessary size can probably be reduced by allowing/simulating "overspill". Water usage should take evaporation losses into account.